# How to make toolbar transparent programmatically while using a DrawerLayout and Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-support-design

My question is how do I do make the ActionBar transparent (and also the status bar)?

I'm having trouble trying to make use of the AppBarLayout and Toolbars on Android to achieve that.

I need that because I want to create an application that has one main Activity that holds a DrawerLayout and many screens which are mostly fragments. Then, there is some screens where the ActionBar and StatusBar becomes transparent (while still having the hamburger button for the DrawerLayout).

I've tried changing the AppBarLayout and the Toolbar, but it looks weird... It looks like there are some weird margins on the ActionBar.

```
appBarLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent));
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent));
```

And here is the result:

[image: Result]

And here is it before changing the color/changing it back:

[image]

Any ideas on how to achieve the transparency on the ActionBar when some fragments are attached to the main content of the main Activity?

If you want to take a look at the code, here is the repository: [Sample Repo](https://github.com/daividssilverio/TransparentActionBarWithDrawerToggleAndMultipleFragments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay...

I made a mistake here...

First, all you need to do is remove the paddings on the content_main.xml and set the elevation of the appBarLayout to 0 and the code will work. (You'd need to set it back to its original value if you need the shadows).

I updated the repo to fix that and it should be working now.

But, There is another way to solve this problem using a fragment with its own AppBarLayout/Toolbar and hiding and showing the MainActivity AppBarLayout when you're showing the Fragment inner one.

I'll create a branch in the same repository to show what I mean.

Please, answer/comment with better solutions/ideas if have them.

[Repo here.](https://github.com/daividssilverio/TransparentActionBarWithDrawerToggleAndMultipleFragments)

Comment: I've made the multiple toolbar solution in the branch I cited and it's working. Please let me know if you have better(more elegant) solutions.